# Why am I not being able to tar /opt and move it to my USB location in Linux

Tags: command-line, tar

I am trying to preform this command to tar `/opt` and move it to my  usb with directory:

```
/media/usb-sdb1-1-7-1/
```

However I am getting an **error**

here is the command I am preforming:

```
tar czf /opt/opt.tar.gz /media/usb-sdb1-1-7-1/
```

here is the error

> tar: Removing leading `/' from member names tar: /opt/opt.tar.gz:
>
> Cannot open: Read-only file system tar: Error is not recoverable:
>
> exiting now

I even tried with sudo but I got this error

```
sh: sudo: command not found
```

Comment: Are you trying to extract to archive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to archive the `/opt` directory recursively and save that tar archive to your external USB-harddrive mounted on `/media/usb-sdb1-1-7-1`, use this:

```
tar -czvf /media/usb-sdb1-1-7-1/opt.tar.gz /opt/
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `tar -xzvf file.tar.gz "/media/usb-sdb1-1-7-1/"` to extract the archive.

Comment: Whatever the OP wants, now he has both answers... =)

Comment: @chaos Oops, I think yours is what he wants. He writes about it in the first line but it get unclearer in the remainder of his question.